# Microsoft Translator - 502 Errors

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

Yesterday, the Microsoft Translator service started returning 502 errors from the API after working for most of the day.  No code changes on our side.  It has been down for over 12 hours now.

Microsoft has a test website (https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/bing/microsofttranslator) that also returns the error, so I am pretty confident it is not our code.  The error that site returns is:

```
The request resulted in a backend time out or backend error. The team
is investigating the issue. We are sorry for the inconvenience. (502)
```

The support site is horrible so not confident my emails are going to anyone.  I have tried valid keys from two different accounts and still getting the errors.  Anybody else having this issue??

[Screen shot of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inf34.png)

Comment: I understand dealing with their customer support isn't fun, but this question is off topic for SO, as it's not about programming. Try some forums maybe?

Comment: I understand your perspective, but at this point I am not sure what the issue is so trying multiple angles.  MS does not have any official support channel for Microsoft Translate apparently (other than for billing) so I cannot even call a phone number and pay for help.  Their own forums are stale and no one from MS appears to be answering questions.  I am not sure if something has changed with their API (which would be a programming issue) or if MS Translate is just a dying service and no one over there cares.

Comment: @AgataB - I strongly recommend that this question remain open. The answer does involve coding changes (switching APIs) and the problem itself is very specific. And this page comes up as a top hit on Google when searching for solutions to this problem.

Comment: Hm, that's fair. I didn't quite get that when I first read it, but yes, I see it. Retracting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a support centre for your favourite service.

Answer (score 1):

We are also having this issue. It appears that v1 of the translator has been discontinued (or is out of service). However v2 of the API works.

I am guessing you are using the form of authentication that only requires your MS datamarket account key (the one found here: https://datamarket.azure.com/account/keys).

With this form of authentication you use code similar to the following to do the translation:

```
Microsoft.TranslatorContainer xlator = new Microsoft.TranslatorContainer("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate");
xlator.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("account key, "account key");
DataServiceQuery<Microsoft.Translation> xlateQry = xlator.Translate("translate me", "en", "fr");
Microsoft.Translation xlateResult = xlateQry.Execute().First();
translateOutput = xlateResult.Text;
```

The TranslatorContainer and Translation classes within the Microsoft namespace come from generated code that MS provided with the first version of the translation.

This is what we did and it quit working yesterday for us as well. It appears that MS has forcefully (and secretly AFAIK) discontinued this form of authentication in favor of their newer authentication scheme and API. It is worth noting that you are not able to access documentation for v1 of the API anymore when navigating from the MS translate API home pages.

However, I was able to follow the instructions for v2 of the API at these URLs to successfully create an ad-hoc HTTP translation request using my existing account:

[Using the HTTP Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512387.aspx)

[Obtaining an Access Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx)

When looking at "Obtaining an Access Token" go to the bottom PowerShell example for the specific URLs and remember to use POST to get the auth token and GET for the translate request. Also remember to use the url encoded parameters for the auth token request. I only say so, because those are the things that tripped me up when working through the example using PostMan in Chrome for the ad-hoc requests.

It may very well be that this transition was well documented, but for some poor sap like myself that is inheriting an application that used v1 of the translate API it sure looks like MS just left everyone using v1 out in the cold, because it is not obvious when navigating the translate API documentation that there are even 2 versions let alone that one will be discontinued.

Comment: So after 3 DAYS of downtime, this started working again yesterday.  I did receive a note from the MS Translate team:  "Sincere apologies form the team for breaking this in the first place and taking quite a while to fix. We were missing a test case."  @Ian you are not missing anything - very unclear if there is a transition from v1 to v2.  This link does refer to a transition to Azure at the end of Oct 2016, but I do not find it particularly helpful:  https://translatorbusiness.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1078534-microsoft-translator-on-azure